# Cocoa: can't stop my 2 sibling views from overlapping

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a view that I'm taking and making full screen. My view is setup as follows:

[image: view setup]

The sibling views 1 and 2 and locked on each other and arrow = spring and line = strut

However once my window appears the bottom sibling view takes up the entire screen and the top sibling view overlays ontop of it like so:

[image: actual]

I've spent a bit of time trying everything I can think of. (like different springs and struts) How can I get the views to remain like I have them setup and not overlap each other?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sibling 2 shouldn't have a top strut or spring. They are causing sibling 2 to remain fixed to the top of the superview rather than the bottom. If you want sibling 2 to adjust it's size vertically and remain a fixed distance from sibling 1, it needs to be done in code or using auto-layout. If you can switch to auto-layout I would recommend that as this configuration is trivial to do using a NSLayoutConstraint between the two sibling views.